# Service-based Database connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I'm using service-based database, so db file is stored with the program. It makes it easier for the end-user, when they can easily move the app with the db to another computer.

Here is my connection string for it:

> add name="DBEnitity"
>   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data
>   source=SQLEXPRESS2008;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;integrated
>   security=True;user
>   instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework""
>   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

But it won't connect if I test it on machine with a SQL Server Express 2012 installed. Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: does `source=SQLEXPRESS2008`  matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `data source=.` to connect to a default instance of sql server, or `data source=.\SQLSERVERNAME` for sql server named instance

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
data source=.
```

where `.` means local SQL server.